# Logic Apps - Recurrence Scheduler

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a workflow that is scheduled to run every minute. The workflow typically completes within 30 seconds. Occasionally the workflow will take longer to complete. If the workflow takes more then 1 minute to run the next workflow will be started before the previous one finishes. How can I stop the next workflow from starting if there is one currently running?

Comment: Hi @paul, I have given a solution below. If it helps please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your Logic App to pick up and run only one instance, then you can just go ahead and configure your workflow Trigger Settings -> Concurrency control and toggle the button.

[image]

By default, Logic App instances run at the same time, or in parallel. This control changes how new runs are executed and can't be changed after enabling. To run as many parallel instances as possible, leave this control turned off. To limit the number of parallel runs, turn on this control, and select a limit. To run sequentially, select 1 as the limit.

I hope this helps.